# C# UserPrincipal.ChangePassword for local accounts is broken after KB3167679 and KB3177108

Tags: c#, active-directory, change-password

Since Microsoft release the two following patches, my C# code just stopped working and always sends back an error message (The system cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request. Please try again later.) when trying to change the password.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3167679

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3177108

```
private void ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
{
   string machineName = Environment.MachineName;
   string contextUser = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", machineName, username);

   using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, machineName, null, ContextOptions.Negotiate, contextUser, oldPassword))
   using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username))
   {
      user.ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword);
   }
}
```

If the submitted credential is not valid, i get a specific error message saying bad username or password so the submitted credential is valid.

I tried many scenarios and they all fail:

- Use the user/password of the user i want to change its password for the PrincipalContext.
- Use a different user/password for the PrincipalContext.
- User a local admin user/password for the PrincipalContext.

None works.

Read a lot about this "new behavior" and i can't seem to find a way to change a valid, not locked, not disabled local user.

Those posts are similar to mine and it seems like some people got a workaround but only for Active Directory and not local user accounts.

[C# Active Directory Invoke “ChangePassword” cannot contact domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282235/c-sharp-active-directory-invoke-changepassword-cannot-contact-domain/39298442)

[Changing Active Directory user passwords in c#/asp.net after MS patch KB3167679](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38997727/changing-active-directory-user-passwords-in-c-asp-net-after-ms-patch-kb3167679/39273962)

[c# Change AD password Directoryservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38969255/c-sharp-change-ad-password-directoryservices/39277553)

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code and explain me why it broke since the patches please?

Comment: try `new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, null, null, ContextOptions.Negotiate, contextUser, oldPassword)` because to indicate the local store machinename should be null, not the machinename

Comment: Tried it but still getting the same error message. Passing null or the machine name into the 2nd argument does the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the password for a local user you should be able to use [NetUserChangePassword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

That still works for me. At least for the local machine (use the name of that as the domain name parameter).

Comment: Looking for a full managed code solution. Not unmanaged code.

Comment: Well, can't help you with that. Why the need for full managed code though? This is just a single and rather simple function, should be no risks to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has updated this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3177108 . Here they have given us problems created by the original "fixes" as well as some tips for working with Kerberos and self-service password reset.

As of October 11, 2016 Microsoft re-released the patches associated with https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms16-101.aspx to resolve issues caused by the original updates (which you can read in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3177108 including the fact that you could no longer change passwords on local accounts-- see "known issue #3").

So in short you should be able to change local passwords now with the latest updates (October 11, 2016).